# Switching between RTL and LTR UIViews in iOS5

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios5, right-to-left

I want to know how to switch between RTL and LTR UIViews on iOS5 storyboard. In android there are two different layout dir's eg: layout-ar (for arabic) and layout (for all other language LTR) . So can we do similar stuff in XCODE or is there any other way of implementing RTL.

Comment: Anyone who has good handson working on switching between RTL and LTR for same views comment !!!!

Comment: Do we have to create two StoryBoards one for LTR(Left to Right Scripts) and one for RTL(right to left scripts). If so is there system support to switch between the two storyBoards.